# What packages do I need to install to accomplish a "vue build <src path> --config <config file path> --dist <dist location> --prod --lib" command?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, build, vuejs3

I've forked an old Vue.js package that has some issues in it (v-money) and made the necessary changes to accomplish what I need. But now when I try to build using the package's original method, I'm getting an error:

`npm run build`

```
vue build ./src/index.js --config ./build.config.js --dist ./dist/ --prod --lib "--disable-compress"

Usage: vue build [options]

alias of "npm run build" in the current project

Options:
  -h, --help  display help for command

  Unknown option --config.
```

I'm guessing I've got the wrong version of Vue.js installed, as the package didn't indicate what version it's supposed to be, but I can't find anything on the web that shows --config, --dist, --prod, and --lib as build options for Vue.js.

I've attempted to build the package as-is without any of my small changes and that fails in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the following dev dependencies from the root of the `v-money` project:

```sh
npm i -D vue-cli@2.8.2 \
         uglify-es \
         uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@^1
```

Edit `build.config.js` to use the Uglify dependencies installed above:

```js
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    ⋮
    plugins: [
      new UglifyJSPlugin(),
      ⋮
    ]
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/v-money-build?file=build.config.js)